Checking keystore is using TEE
I am developing an app on android 10.0 sdk 29device.
I know KeyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware Returns 'true‘ it means that key is stored inside of TEE. And the log returns true
However my device log says
07-24 16:15:14.992  2053  2053 I android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-impl: Fetching keymaster device name default
07-24 16:15:14.993  2053  2053 I android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-impl: Could not find any keystore module, using software-only implementation.
07-24 16:15:14.995  2053  2053 I ServiceManagement: Registered android.hardware.keymaster@3.0::IKeymasterDevice/default (start delay of 148ms)
07-24 16:15:14.995  2053  2053 I ServiceManagement: Removing namespace from process name android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service to keymaster@3.0-service.
07-24 16:15:14.996  2053  2053 I android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Registration complete for android.hardware.keymaster@3.0::IKeymasterDevice/default.
07-24 16:15:16.934  1971  1971 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.keymaster@4.0::IKeymasterDevice/default in either framework or device manifest.
07-24 16:15:16.945  2148  2148 I keystore: found android.hardware.keymaster@3.0::IKeymasterDevice with interface name default and seclevel SOFTWARE
07-24 16:15:16.945  2148  2148 W keystore: No secure Keymaster implementation found, but device offers insecure Keymaster HAL. Using as default.

And there's file created
/data/misc/keystore/user_0/.1000_chr_USRPKEY_mankey /data/misc/keystore/user_0/1000_USRPKEY_mankey

So I am very confused about this contradictory results.
Do you guys think TEE is activated?
As far as I know if the device is using TEE, key files shouldn't be created in data/misc/keystore folder

Seems like TEE isn't activated, and key was created in a software (unsecured env).
The security measures provided by TEE is the env itself and not the key (meaning the creation of a key doesn't implicitly hints there's a TEE).
From Android source code:
    if (result[SecurityLevel::SOFTWARE] && !result[SecurityLevel::TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT]) {
        LOG(WARNING) << "No secure Keymaster implementation found, but device offers insecure"
                        " Keymaster HAL. Using as default.";
        result[SecurityLevel::TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT] = result[SecurityLevel::SOFTWARE];
        result[SecurityLevel::SOFTWARE] = nullptr;
    }

